# How do I block the UI using JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've been using this plugin to block the UI: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

The plugin works excellently, it's just that I'd be enormously surprised if jQuery UI didn't do such a thing already, given that it must do effectively the same thing for it's Dialog feature.

How does one block the UI using JQuery UI?

Comment: What's wrong with just using the BlockUI plugin? It's pretty lightweight.

Comment: @Alastair: Nothing -- more of a thought experiment is all. It's an awesome plugin,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something hacky - call the modal, then on the `onopen` callback, `remove()` the modal itself.

```
$("#something").dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { $('.ui-dialog').remove(); }
});
```

Hey! I said it was hacky :)

*or*

Examine the Modal code and see if it calls a function to block the UI. Perhaps you could add an external reference to it so you can call it yourself.

*or*

Add this HTML to you document, and call `show()` or `hide()` on it.

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 32767;"></div>
```

*or (if you are unsure how they are made)*

They are simply a `div` (commonly) absolutely positioned and 100% `height`/`width`, with a high `z-index` and usually an `opacity` (check out how to do it in IE6 with filters).

You can also set it to `position: fixed` so it will always be there if you scroll. You can also hide the scrollbars if you want by doing `$('body').css({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })`.

Answer (score 2):

To "block" the UI, you just insert an absolutely positioned div with a high z-index and desired background color and opacity such that it covers the whole page.

Comment: I think he knows *how* to, but *can* he do it with jQuery UI? i.e. not write his own code and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery have only a progress bar as I know. Of course you can do all above but it looks too complicate to manage if you compare with what you are using already.

My recommandation is to try changing [jQuery Block UI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

Really clean and have many CSS options. Easy to use and implement on any project.

Comment: @BillyONeal I think you didn't read my answer: "what you are using already" is in front of your eyes.

Comment: The question says "I've been using this plugin to block the UI. How would I implement such using only jQuery UI components (rather than this plugin)" Your answer says "Try using this plugin which you explicitly said you didn't want to use in the question"

Comment: Do we discuss English grammar here or programming? I think is rude to vote down just because you don't get the point.

Comment: My answer was: "My recommandation is to try changing jQuery Block UI" Please read all the answer and if you don't get it just refrain yourself to post negative comments.

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether or not I "get" it. It has everything to do with my explicit disclaimer that this was not a valid answer in my question. The question says "I know about library XYZ. How might I accomplish what library XYZ does without library XYZ?" Your answer is "use library XYZ", which was explicitly disallowed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="__messageBox_wait" class="messageBoxArea" style="display: none; cursor: default">
                <div>
                    <label id="__messageBox_wait_text" style="vertical-align: middle">
                        Please wait</label>
                </div>
</div>

function blockUI() {
        var boxHtml = $('#__messageBox_wait');
        var message = "Please wait...";
        $('#__messageBox_wait_text').text(message);
        $.blockUI({
            theme: false,
            title: 'Message',
            message: boxHtml,
            css: 'width:15%'
        });
    }


    $.unblockUI(); -- call to Unblock UI
     blockUI();  --- call to block UI
```